# Google Tag Manager Code displayed in event

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am having some trouble with my Google Tag Manager. The code is working great, but on the event the code is visible for the user! Example of the code shown in the browser

> dataLayer.push({'event':'record','km_event':'logged in'....})

I haven't seen others with this issue and I can't understand where this is part of code is shown! The google tag manager code which I am using (header):

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','---CODE---');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
     <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=--CODE---" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: Can you please show us your entire dataLayer push code (without using ...) as well as how you setup your Google Analytics tag setup please.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you mean by "..but on the event the code is visible for the user!"... it would be useful to see code where you are calling dataLayer.push function

Comment: Just fixed the issue by making a seperate .js file with this code!

Answer (score 1):

Clientside javascript is always visible! Even if you make a seperate .js file like you said, Javascript on the web is executed in a "sandbox environment" in the clients browser, so no matter what the code can always be seen.

Comment: Client side code is not "always visible". You might be always able to inspect it if you look at the page source , but client side javascript is not visible in the rendered page if wrapped in script tags. Since per the OP's comment the code disappeared when they used an external file they have probably forgot the scrip tags (external files do not require them).

Comment: If you can inspect it @EikePierstorff then for me it's visible.. :)